# How to extract an uploaded file from a body that is StringIO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typhoeus

I'm trying out Typhoeus for the first time to upload a file to a Rails app, but I don't know how to turn that file into something I can use.

The upload is done like Typheous' example:

```
Typhoeus.put(
  url,
  body: {
    title: "This should be the title",
    file: File.open(file_path, "r")
  }
)
```

In the controller, `request.body.string` is this:

```
 "title=This%20should%20be%20the%20title&file=%5B%221-1381398552.zip%22%2C%20%22application%2Fzip%22%2C%20%22%2Fvagrant%2Fppc_reports%2Fspec%2Fdummy%2Ftmp%2F1381398547_qyforj%2F1-1381398552.zip%22%5D"
```

How can I get the file from the body and save it as a File or Tempfile to work with?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? I think StringIO is supposed to behave like a file.

```
contents = params[:file].read
```

After that you'd just save it to another file.

```
File.open('/path/to/file', 'rw') do |f|
  f.write contents
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `params` doesn't include `:file`.

Comment: I'm assuming that the request.body object doesn't either? What does it include when you run this:

`Rails.logger.info request.body.inspect`
`Rails.logger.info params.inspect`

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` doesn't default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (in contrast to `POST`), you have to set it:

```
Typhoeus.put(
  url,
  body: {
    title: "This should be the title",
    file: File.open(file_path, "r")
  },
  headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
)
```